# Comparing best linear fit model between two populations with different sample sizes

Tags: bootstrap, sample-size, linear

I have theoretical information about 100,000 molecules, and experimental information about 80 molecules. In both cases, I compared the variables `X` and `Y`, and ended up with a theoretical and experimental linear model as follows:

```
Yt = 1.4 x Xt - 0.5 
Ye = 1.7 x Xe - 4.5
```

I am unsure if these two equations can be compared to understand the relationship between the `X` and `Y` variable in theoretical versus experimental conditions. After all, the theoretical equation is derived from many-fold larger sample size.

I was considering bootstrapping. Such as taking many samples of size 80 (with replacement) from the experimental data, and calculating the linear model for each sample, and then using that to inform how robust the linear model for the experimental data was ... in order to compensate for the fact that the experimental data has a much smaller sample size than the theoretical data.

However, I am not sure if that is the correct approach. Or if I should, say, take samples of size 80 from the larger theoretical data to see how its linear equation would be if it were a smaller sample size.

Basically, I'm unsure if any of my ideas are sound.

How can this problem be resolved?